# React route being concatenated to rather than refreshed to intended route

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I have my routes in App.js as follows:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import SinglePost from './components/SinglePost';
import Post from './components/Post';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavBar />

      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        <Route path='/post' exact component={Post} />
        <Route path='/post/:slug' component={SinglePost} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

The routes work fine in the browser until it comes time to navigate to a route from '/post/:slug'...from that route, everything gets concatenated to the '/post' route like '/post/about' or '/post/post'. The only route that refreshes to its intended route from 'post/:slug' is home ('/').

I'm having trouble putting my finger on why the route to Home from SinglePost works as intended but the others retain '/post/' at the beginning.

I am by no means a React or React Router pro, so it may be something obvious I am just missing due to my inexperience.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: <Link to={"/post/" + post.slug.current} key={post.slug.current}>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment by @vpalmerini is the solution:

> Oh, I guess that it's concatenating your route because your 
> doesn' have a / right before the route. In this case it appends to the
> current location. Try to add it as <NavLink to="/about"}> for
> instance...that should do the trick – @vpalmerini

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the order of your routes inside `<Switch>` and remove `exact` property:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavBar />

      <Switch>
        <Route path='/post/:slug' component={SinglePost} />
        <Route path='/post' component={Post} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        <Route path='/' component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

I usually recommend to put the most specific routes on top because `<Switch>` will always choose the first one that matches, and this way you don't need to use `exact` (at least in your example), which can be tricky sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but still getting the same behavior after rearranging the order of the routes. I can't put my finger on why the Home route works correctly from the SinglePost route but none of the others do.

Comment: I see. Can you share how are you navigating between routes (if by `history.push()` or `<Link>` for instance)?

Comment: This is the link to a single post in the Post.js file: ```<Link to={"/post/" + post.slug.current} key={post.slug.current}>```

Comment: The NavBar.js links are ```<NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>```, ```<NavLink to "post">Blog Posts</NavLink>```, and ```<NavLink to="about">About</NavLink>```.

Comment: Okay. Just to be sure, this `<Link to={"/post/" + post.slug.current} key={post.slug.current}>` does not go to `/post/:slug`? What is the value of `post.slug.current`?

Comment: Oh, I guess that it's concatenating your route because your `<NavLink>` doesn' have a `/` right before the route. In this case it appends to the current location. Try to add it as `<NavLink to="/about"}>` for instance...that should do the trick

Comment: Welp, that was the key...replaced "about" with "/about" and "post" with "/post" in the <NavLink> for both and works as intended. Good catch and thank you!

Comment: great! glad to help